# Fan on Mac Book Air & Finder crash always

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, finder, crash

This is my first question here. So I hope to be clear in my explanation.

I own a Mac Book Air 13-Inch Mid 2013, 1,7 GB, 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3.
OSX Yosemite. Version 10.10.2

**FINDER CRASH**
Every time I turn on the Mac finder crash.
OS show this message
"the last time you opened finder it unexpectedly quit while reopening windows"

Any ideas whit this issue?

I had tried  Solution

Open the Terminal app.
Type: sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -force
Press Return.
When prompted, enter your OS X user password, and press Return.
Wait until the text prompt returns, at which point the process will be complete.
Restart the computer.

FAN
The Fan stay lot of time on and there is no software open.

Thanks in advance for your comments

Pablo

Comment: use SMC reset to get your Fan to behave. shift+ctrl+alt+power

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd try is to remove the saved state - assuming you can get that far…

navigate to `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.finder.savedState/`
& delete that entire folder content.

If you can't get far enough to do that, it can be done from single user at boot, but I'd need someone smarter than me to fill the details, so post a comment or revise your question if that's the case.